# Eclipse Indigo 3.7 no more validation of PHP (PDT) or Javascript code

Tags: php, javascript, eclipse-indigo

i installed the new Eclipse Indigo 3.7 SDK.
And i installed the PDT and Javascript Plugin to edit PHP and Javascript files.

For some reason my php files and javascript files are not validated.
Java code is still validated showing the red rectangles on the right side indicating that there is an error or yellow rectangles for warnings.

Do i need to set something up to get this working. Looks like many things in the preferences changed, so i cannot find any of menu items described in some of the tutorial describing how to enable validation or add libraries for javascript validation.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Just found a work-around now : following the steps presented here made my day : 
http://www.mmncs.com/2011/08/how-to-install-setup-a-local-php-development-environment-in-linux-ubuntu-11-04-with-eclipse-indigo-3-7-lamp-xdebug-developer/

(scroll to "Install PHP Development Tools (PDT)" ).

In short : install the classic workbench, then install PDT from the workbench.

Works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues and moved to netbeans (configuration takes two minutes!)